# Codedeploy deployment failing at BeforeInstall event with error "exit: 0 : numeric argument required"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I have the following in my appspec file (yaml validated) -

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: some/source
    destination: some/destination
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: beforeInstall.sh
  AfterInstall:
    - location: afterInstall.sh
```

I am getting the following error ***intermittently*** on the BeforeInstall step -

```
Error Code ScriptFailed
Script Name beforeInstall.sh
Message Script at specified location: beforeInstall.sh failed with exit code 255
Log Tail

LifecycleEvent - BeforeInstall
Script - beforeInstall.sh
[stderr]/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/edbe4bd2-3999-4820-b782-42d8aceb18e6/d-4GJ8QS9MG/deployment-archive/beforeInstall.sh: line 1: exit: 0
: numeric argument required
```

Following is the content of my beforeInstall.sh file -

```
exit 0
```

Note that the build succeeds intermittently. I tried the following -

- doing dos2unix of the beforeInstall.sh file. Ran build and it succeeded after some trials (not immediately after the change), so cannot say that it was the reason.
- uploaded a fresh zip to S3 with a new name of the zip file (just in order to avoid any caching that might be happening at the ec2 instances).

Also, I found that even when the build succeeded, the file changes as mentioned in the files section did not happen in the instances - Files to be added did not get added, file modifications did not happen. However, the timestamp of some existing files got modified to today. Weird.

**Update**

Following is the log trail from `/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log`, with `exit 1` in beforeInstall.sh -

```
2016-08-01 12:41:01 WARN  [codedeploy-agent(9507)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::HookExecutor: Script at specified location: beforeInstall.sh is not executable.  Trying to make it executable.
2016-08-01 12:41:01 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(9507)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version.
2016-08-01 12:41:01 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(9507)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.087513 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Failed",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{\"error_code\":4,\"script_name\":\"beforeInstall.sh\",\"message\":\"Script at specified location: beforeInstall.sh run as user sandeepan failed with exit code 255\",\"log\":\"LifecycleEvent - BeforeInstall\\nScript - beforeInstall.sh\\n[stderr]/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/c71b93a2-8561-41e2-b90f-d638548e7b4c/d-A36YRE23H/deployment-archive/beforeInstall.sh: line 1: exit: 0\\r: numeric argument required\\n\"}"},host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiQ29kZURlcGxveS91cy1lYXN0LTEvUHJvZC9hcm46YXdzOnNkczp1cy1lYXN0LTE6Mzc3NzAzOTYxOTk4OmRlcGxveW1lbnQvZC1BMzZZUkUyM0giLCJob3N0SWQiOiJhcm46YXdzOmVjMjp1cy1lYXN0LTE6Mzc3NzAzOTYxOTk4Omluc3RhbmNlL2ktZWZmYzU1YWEiLCJjb21tYW5kTmFtZSI6IkFmdGVySW5zdGFsbCIsImNvbW1hbmRQb3NpdGlvbiI6NSwiY29tbWFuZEF0dGVtcHQiOjF9XQ==")

2016-08-01 12:41:01 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(9507)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Error during perform: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::ScriptError - Script at specified location: beforeInstall.sh run as user sandeepan failed with exit code 255 - /opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:153:in `execute_script'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:110:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:98:in `each'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:98:in `block in execute'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:168:in `create_script_log_file_if_needed'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:96:in `execute'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:133:in `block (3 levels) in map'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:124:in `each'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in map'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:62:in `execute_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_poller.rb:132:in `process_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_poller.rb:65:in `perform'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/agent/base.rb:28:in `run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:38:in `block in run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:55:in `with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:37:in `run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:70:in `block in run_with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:55:in `with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:69:in `run_with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:33:in `block in start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:22:in `loop'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:22:in `start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:202:in `block in spawn_child'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:200:in `fork'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:200:in `spawn_child'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:192:in `block in spawn_children'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:191:in `times'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:191:in `spawn_children'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:134:in `start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:37:in `block in start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:36:in `fork'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:36:in `start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/bin/codedeploy-agent:37:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/command_support.rb:130:in `call'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/command_support.rb:130:in `execute'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/app_support.rb:262:in `block in call_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/app_support.rb:275:in `call'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/app_support.rb:275:in `call_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/app_support.rb:69:in `run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/bin/codedeploy-agent:84:in `<main>'
```

***Note - I am able to reproduce this error only when my shell script contains an exit.***

Also, I am not sure what the shebang line (#!/bin/sh) has anything to do with this. I tried by adding it (verified that there is something at /bin/sh) - 
`ls -l /bin/sh` gives - 
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jun  3 22:23 /bin/sh -> bash`

Deploying with that change gives the following error at beforeInstall step - `[stderr]bash: /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/c71b93a2-8561-41e2-b90f-d638548e7b4c/d-UOGT00Z2H/deployment-archive/beforeInstall.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: Do you use Windows for editing scripts?  If so, which editor?

Comment: Did you get a chance to confirm if you are having line ending issues?

Comment: I will check that again on Monday. I remember doing dos2unix for the files earlier.

Comment: Sure report back if you can.  The ^M means during that invocation, there was a line ending problem.  So it looks to me that it is still and issue.

Answer (score 1):

**I would focus on Windows vs Linux line endings.**

You have provided two different errors in the question and comments area. Both of those messages point directly to line ending issues:

```
exit: 0 : numeric argument required

/bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

The ^M you see in that error message is the carriage return character CR (Carriage return, '\r', 0x0D, 13 in decimal). Linux uses the line feed character to designate the end of a line, but Windows uses the character sequence CR + LF. Your file has Windows line endings, which is confusing the Linux shell, and causing those error messages.

Until you resolve this, all manner of troubleshooting will fail you.

Until you can get your editing environment to write the files with Linux line endings, try the following:

1. Use dos2unix on the Linux box to correct the problem with both files.
2. Confirm those files run on the server manually. This is important.
3. Copy those files down to your development box.
4. Create the CodeDeploy revision archive using these corrected files. Do not edit these files locally.
5. Redeploy the archive.

I expect that the CodeDeploy will then work normally.

I have spent days chasing this exact issue with line endings and CodeDeploy.  It is hard to track, especially the  `exit: 0 : numeric argument required` message. It is rather obtuse, and has nothing to do with exit codes, or shebangs.  Its the line endings.

Comment: I tried reproducing the issue but could not anymore. I manually edited the beforeInstall.sh file using edit++ editor on windows and uploaded the zip to S3 and the deployment succeeded.

Comment: Awarding the bounty however. Thanks for taking out your time to help!

Answer (score 0):

This seems due to the script itself ran failed from the message "Script at specified location: beforeInstall.sh run as user sandeepan failed with exit code 255". Can you run the script alone without CodeDeploy, and make sure the script works?

Comment: How do I run the script manually? Which is the location? Does the script exist after the deployment is over? Do I need to go and check its deployment archive?